# p:remoteCommand destroys @ViewScoped managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, destroy, view-scope, remotecommand

I am having trouble adding a p:remoteCommand to a form. It looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/util"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Reset Test</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/treetable-sscce/css/example.css" />
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
    </h:head>

    <div class="box">
        <h2>Box</h2>
        <h:panelGroup id="mypanel">
            Headline: <h:outputText value="#{resetBean.headline}" />
            <br/>
            Message : <h:outputText value="#{resetBean.message}" />
            <br/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <h2>Form</h2>
        <h:form id="myform" acceptcharset="utf-8">

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" severity="info, warn" />       

            <!--  register custom validate event -->
            <f:event listener="#{resetBean.validateForm}" type="postValidate" />

            <p:remoteCommand name="resetByEscape" action="#{resetBean.resetAction}" 
                immediate="true" update=":myform :mypanel" />

            <h:outputLabel for="headline">Meldungsüberschrift</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="headline" value="#{resetBean.headline}" />
            <br/>

            <h:outputLabel for="message">Meldungsüberschrift</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputTextarea id="message" value="#{resetBean.message}" />
            <br/>

            <h:commandButton action="#{resetBean.resetAction}"  
                        value="Reset" immediate="true" onclick="resetForm()"/>

            <h:commandButton action="#{resetBean.submitAction}" value="Submit"  immediate="false"/>

        </h:form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

        var resetForm = function()
        {
            $("[id$='headline']").val(null)
            $("[id$='message']").val(null)
        }

        var escapePressed = function()
        {
            resetForm();
            resetByEscape();
        } 

        $(document).keyup(function(e) {if (e.keyCode == 27) escapePressed();});

        //--><!]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

Here is the bean code:

```
package de.example.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ResetBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7282752623428425109L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ResetBean.class);

    protected String headline = null;
    protected String message = null;

    public ResetBean() {
        log.error("ResetBean");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        log.error("postConstruct");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        log.error("preDestroy");
    }

    public void resetAction() {
        log.error("resetAction");
        headline = null;
        message = null;
    }

    public void submitAction() {
        log.error("submitAction headline="+headline+" message="+message);
    }

    public void validateForm(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws ValidatorException {
        log.error("validateForm");
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Both the `h:command` button and the `p:remoteCommand` execute the same action in the same fashion. The difference is, that the `h:command` button responds to a mouse click, while the ESC key triggers the `p:remoteCommand` via javascript on using ESC key.

The problem is, that the route via `p:remoteCommand` seems to destroy the backing bean somehow (the bean is `@ViewScoped`). The `@PreDestroy` annotated method is never called, however: the next action on the page after using the `p:remoteCommand` forces the component to be created from scratch! Default constructor and `@PostConstruct` are called. Naturally some important parameters are missing now and the whole view gets shot to hell.

Any idea what is happening? Why the difference between `p:remoteCommmand` and `h:commandButton` in this instance? Any chance of working around the problem?

Comment: Can you post your bean code?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of the office for a while. I'm afraid I can not post the full code because it's simply too big. I'll post an excerpt that contains the action methods involved.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error in smaller context. If you can do it it'll be fine. Posting an excerpt will probably make so difficult to get a clear answer.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem in a demo project. I am editing the problem description accordingly in a minute.

Comment: That's the cool way of doing things ;-)

Comment: Can you provide more info about the issue? JSF impl version, browser you're using... I've tried it with Chrome and works as expected, although firefox is bringing unexpected behaviour. However, unrelated to your problem, you don't need to clear your form using JS. Just clear their model values at java code and you'll get inputs cleared when coming back from the post.

Comment: Primefaces: 3.5, JSF(mojarra) 2.2.3, Chrome (32.0.1700.77) and Firefox (26.0) on Ubuntu. The problem is consistent on those two browsers.

Comment: I get the feeling something goes wrong in the restore view stage. Could it be related to having javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING set to true?

Comment: The problem is view state parameter (the one used by JSF implementations for keeping the view stateful) is removed when clicking on ESC. Just have a look at the generated form at client side. I would bet it actually is a problem related with `p:remoteCommand`, since the problem seems to be related with all the keys and not only ESC. Maybe you should open a thread in PF forum...

Comment: Hm ... so this is a PF bug?

Comment: Not sure at all, it could be Mojarra related. You should notify it at PrimeFaces forum to Cagatay's team. They will help you with the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post the answer here once I have it.

Comment: Does it happen, if you remove f:event?

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem. In my case and maybe the same case here (question provides only 'sample' code, not real one) it was caused by nested forms template->page.

If you have a ui:composition template or something similar to that, at the end of the generated HTML on client side it may creates nested forms like this:

```
<h:form>
...
  <h:form>
   ...
  </h:form>
...
</h:form>
```

which is invalid HTML code.

Remove unnecessary forms or reorganize code and test again. It should not call `@postConstruct` method when `p:remoteCommand` is called through JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for that. It's been over a year, so I'm not 100% sure, but I think this had nothing to do with stacked forms.

Comment: Ok, maybe it helps someone else. If you remember, could you post your solution? Thanks!

Comment: If memory serves it was a bug in Primefaces and it was fixed by them.